# Error module not found from custom framework iOS project

Tags: ios, swift

I recently created a framework project to custom all fields for my form by using Eureka lib

I installed Eureka by Pod file

Everything is fine until I create a view controller in my framework

```
import Eureka

open class C2CFormViewController: FormViewController {

}
```

Xcode error shows:

> (fatal) module 'Eureka' not found

If I don't add "open", there is no error
But I have to code "open" because other projects can add my framework to use C2CFormViewController

Error Image
https://ibb.co/Jdf3F0S

What is the problem? How to fix this?